# Origin of the word "elder"

Tags: etymology, i-mutation

I was wondering if this word is in anyway related to some ancient diety or religion, if so which ?

Comment: Which sense? Elder as in the tree or elder as in a person?

Comment: See [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=elder&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: @Mahnax: _[What is the General Reference qualification for questions on word or phrase origin?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1128/5822)_

Answer (score 7):

The entry in [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=elder&allowed_in_frame=0) that Mahnax posted is correct, as far as it goes. But it turns out that *elder* the tree and *elder* = *older* come from different Proto-Indo-European (PIE) roots, according to the AH Dictionary of PIE Roots.

*Elder* the tree (English *elderberry*) comes from the PIE root **el-²* (i.e, the second root in the PIE dictionary that has the shape *el-* -- the asterisk in front of the root is to show that it's reconstructed, not attested -- PIE was spoken long before writing was invented). This root meant 'red, brown'; other English words derived from it include *elm, alder, elk, auk, hellebore,* and *eland*.

*Elder* the comparative form of *old*, on the other hand, comes from the PIE root **al-³*, which means 'to grow or nourish'. A short list of other English words from this root includes *alderman, old, alto, haughty, hawser, altitude, enhance, adult, alumnus, alimony, proletarian*, and *abolish*.

*Elder* = *older* is an example (as Etymonline says) of **[Umlaut](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299)**. Umlaut means changing a back vowel like *a* or *o* to a front vowel like *ä* or *e* in anticipation of a front vowel in the next syllable. This is still a productive process in German, where *alt*, the word for 'old', has a comparative *älter* (pronounced /elter/). But it's no longer productive in Modern English, though it's also responsible for the plural *mice* from *mouse* (originally /mise/ from /mus/ before the Great Vowel Shift).

Comment: Word etymologies are so intriguing. :)