# When to use "the eldest"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, american-english, british-english, articles

Somebody please help me with this question. I know the answer but not sure why we have to use the definite article "the" here. The answer sheet says option "c" is the correct answer. But I am not sure why?

Q.Of my two daughters she is ———.

(A) elder (B) eldest (C) the elder (D) the eldest

Thanks.

Comment: _Eldest_ is an archaic [umlauted](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/67722/15299) form of _oldest_. It's usually limited to family position -- _their eldest is a doctor_.

Comment: As implied by @John above, it's normal to precede ***eldest*** in such contexts by a [determiner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-the-my-some-this) *(the, their, our, etc.)*

Comment: A google of comparative and superlatives will give the explanation you need. "er" is used when comparing 2 things, "est" when comparing a group of things.

Comment: Superlatives of all sorts use _the_; it's an optional but common part of the construction.

Comment: As @LaconicDroid alludes, if it had been "_Of my **three** daughters_", then the answer would have been _**the eldest**_; with only two, it's _**the elder**_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELL

Answer (score 1):

While this answer may seem woefully inadequate, and far too convoluted as compared to the comments already offered, I provide my own two cents.

In my opinion either *option (c)* or *option (d)* would've 'sounded right' – not a definitive scale to compare with, of course, but I admit with some embarrassment it is the one I use the most.

Considering, Superlatives and Comparatives, though, the *option (c)* proves appropriate.

While both sup. and comp. – I hope you pardon the abbreviations – are forms of adverbs or adjectives used for comparison, a Superlative is used to show performance ( in adverbs ) or quality ( in adjectives ) of the greatest or least degree.

Say,

- Amongst the boys, James is the tall*est*.
- Jack is the *best* pick for class prefect.

You will note, of course, the addition of the suffix '-est'. When the word has more than one syllables, you add 'most', 'least', or a derivative before it.

Comparatives, meanwhile, are restricted two merely two things.

Say,

- James is tall*er* than Harry.
- Jack is a *better* pick for class prefect than Tom.

Again, same rules apply, only, the suffix here is '-er,' or you place 'more / less' before.

None of this answers your question, though. Regardless, it was essential to set the base, so that I can proceed further.

The above knocks down our options to only two, either (a) or (c).

Now, you may have noticed that I used for both superlatives the article **the**, but did not bother to do so for comparatives – wherein I had to provide another name for it to become two things.

This is because, when it is a single syllable adjective/adverb-turned-Superlative, we typically write 'the' prior to it.

This is also why I suggested *option (d)* as a contender. While I do not exactly know why we do so, I can offer numerous examples below:

These are, due to convenience, from Jane Austen, for which I hope you will not judge me – did what I could.

[**Northanger Abbey,** *Chapter 4*:](https://austen.thefreelibrary.com/Northanger-Abbey/4-1#eldest)

> The whole being explained, many obliging things were said by the Miss Thorpes of their wish of being better acquainted with her; of being considered as already friends, through the friendship of their brothers, etc., which Catherine heard with pleasure, and answered with all the pretty expressions she could command; and, as the first proof of amity, she was soon invited to accept an arm of *the eldest* Miss Thorpe, and take a turn with her about the room.

[**Northanger Abbey,** *Chapter 9*:](https://austen.thefreelibrary.com/Persuasion/1-9#eldest)

> Charles Hayter was *the eldest* of all the cousins, and a very amiable, pleasing young man, between whom and Henrietta there had been a considerable appearance of attachment previous to Captain Wentworth's introduction.

Above, you could accuse me of nitpicking, but '*an eldest*' clearly won't go in your own question.

Now, I will be very frank with you. The only reason why I fell (a) incorrect is because of the rather puerile 'it does not sound right,' and examples that I have from my research. Most of the books I have searched this for only used 'elder' without a 'the' when they – and yes, I fully realise how bewildering it is to read that sentence – have a 'my', 'her', 'his', etc ahead as an attribute adjective.

To make it simpler, unless and until it was:

- This is my elder brother,
- He is her elder brother,
- She is his elder sister, etc.,

it always had a 'the,' or was converted into a sup. as in the case of

- He is *their* oldest son.

Even War and Peace by Leo Tolstoy has this; '[With her elder sister I was stricter.](https://tolstoy.thefreelibrary.com/War-and-Peace/1-12#elder)'

Now, for the examples I had promised above:

['**The Mourning Brothers**' from Ambrose Bierce's *Fantastic Fables*:](https://bierce.thefreelibrary.com/Fantastic-Fables/124-1#elder)

> So when the Old Man was dead each of the youths put a weed upon his hat and wore it until he was himself old, when, seeing that neither would give in, they agreed that the younger should leave off his weeds and *the elder* give him half of the estate.

From [Charles Dickens' **A Tale Of Two Cities,** *Chapter X*](https://dickens.thefreelibrary.com/Tale-Of-Two-Cities/3-10#elder), I present:

> 'To distinguish the brothers, I will call them *the elder* and the younger; by the elder, I mean him who exercised the most authority. It was the elder who replied, `Since about this hour last night.'

Hence, and because "Of my two daughters she is *the elder*" sounds better than the alternative, "Of my two daughters she is *elder*," I present my argument.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "eldest" should generally follow the practices for all of the "-er"/"-est" words.  Ie; you use "-er" when there are two to be selected from, and "-est" when there are 3 or more (or when the quantity is indeterminate).

Thus:

> Of the two men, Fred is the taller.
>
> Of the three men, Fred is the tallest.
>
> Of the two girls, Barbara is the elder.
>
> Of the three girls, Barbara is the eldest.

However, do note that *elder/eldest* is borderline archaic.  And also note that the word ordering of the first and third examples above "sounds" awkward -- better to say simply "Fred is the taller of the two men".  (For some reason, the "-est" versions don't sound as awkward.)